# Can we get variable that in Try from catch?

Tags: java

Just a simple question here. Can we get the variable that declared inside the Try from catch?

Eg.

```
Try {
.....
String s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
.....
}
catch {
System.out.println(s7);
}
```

I know this is not the way to getting the string `s7`. So, I want to ask that is there any possible way or what do I need to do to get the `s7` in the catch? Any examples, related post or answers to share?

Expected result:
Can get `s7` in the catch.

Thanks for viewing, comments and answers.

p.s. Java Newbie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scope of the `s7` variable is just inside the `try{}` block. For the variable `s7` be usable inside the `catch{}` block you need to increase the [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) of the variable. You can do that by moving the declaration outside the try:

```
String s7 = null;
try {
    .....
    s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
    .....
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (s7 != null) {
      System.out.println(s7);
    } else {
      // s7 is null ...
    }
}
```

You also need to initialize `s7` to some value, else the compiler will warn you about the use of an uninitialized variable. That's because exceptions break normal workflow, and if an exception is thrown your variable `s7` could have not been initialized.

Comment: Hi, is it if we move to outside the try and it will became global variable so we can retrieve the `s7` anywhere?

Comment: @user2709555 Its an scope issue. Ive updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Java code is organized in blocks defined by `{` and `}`. Members defined inside the block are not accessible from outside.

```
{//Block 1
   String outside;
    { //Block 2
      String value = "in block";
      outside = "new Value";
    }
}
```

In above example we have two blocs, we can access to structures in inner blocks. We can decorate those block to create a class and method.

```
class MyClass {

 String outside;

 void method() {
     String value = "in block";
     outside = "new Value";
 }

}
```

Same rule obey to try/catch clause.

```
String s7;

try {
   s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
   //.....
} catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(s7);
}
```

To find out more read: [Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html)

Comment: Thank you Vash for the sharing and teaching! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can define the variable before the try block, then you can access it withing the catch/finally block

```
String s7 = null

Try {
.....
s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
.....
}
catch {
System.out.println(s7);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just declare your variable before the try block.

```
String s7 = null;

Try {
s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
}
catch {
System.out.println(s7);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to delcare s7 outside the try.

```
String s7 = null;
Try {
  .....
  s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
  .....
}
catch {
  System.out.println(s7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try Like this,

```
String s7 = null;
    Try {
    .....
    s7 = ftpfile1.getName().toString();
    .....
    }
    catch {
    System.out.println(s7);
    }
```